# ZipExtFile to Django File

Tags: python, django, file

I am wondering whether there is a way to upload a zip file to django web server and put the zip's files into django database WITHOUT accessing the actual file system in the process (e.g. extracting the files in the zip into a tmp dir and then load them)

Django provides a function to convert python File to Django File, so if there is a way to convert ZipExtFile to python File, it should be fine.

thanks for help!

Django model:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo:
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='somewhere')
```

Usage:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError  
from django.core.files import File  
from io import BytesIO  

z = ZipFile('zipFile')
istream = z.open('subfile')
ostream = BytesIO(istream.read())
tmp = Foo(file=File(ostream))
try:
    tmp.full_clean()
except Validation, e:
    print e
```

Output:

```
{'file': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}
```

[SOLUTION] Solution using an ugly hack:

As correctly pointed out by Don Quest, file-like classes such as StringIO or BytesIO should represent the data as a virtual file. However, Django File's constructor only accepts the build-in file type and nothing else, although the file-like classes would have done the job as well. The hack is to set the variables in Django::File manually:

```
buf = bytesarray(OPENED_ZIP_OBJECT.read(FILE_NAME))
tmp_file = BytesIO(buf)
dummy_file = File(tmp_file)   # this line actually fails
dummy_file.name = SOME_RANDOM_NAME
dummy_file.size = len(buf)
dummy_file.file = tmp_file
# dummy file is now valid
```

Please keep commenting if you have a better solution (except for custom storage)

Comment: Don has the right idea, though the file will still hit the file system unless you use custom file storage.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/

Comment: thanks for the answers. But I do not understand why this would not work directly, as I could easily store the zip file and a file in the zip file should be the same as the original zip file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing to much about Django, i can tell you to take a look at the "io" package.
You could do something like:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import StringIO
zname,zipextfile = 'zipcontainer.zip', 'file_in_archive'
istream = ZipFile(zname).open(zipextfile)
ostream = StringIO(istream.read())
```

And then do whatever you would like to do with your "virtual" ostream Stream/File.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But istream.read() gives you back a byte array instead of a string. And I cannot decode the bytes since they represent an image.

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried then. Although the program does not raise an error, Django has a problem converting BytesIO to django.file...

Comment: No problem! Just use ByteIO instead: see http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=io# for further informations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6073/discussion-between-don-question-and-y-chai)

Answer (score 8):

There's an easier way to do this:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

uploaded_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(uploaded_file, 'r')  # ZipFile

for filename in uploaded_zip.namelist():
    with uploaded_zip.open(filename) as f:  # ZipExtFile
        my_django_file = ContentFile(f.read())
```

Using this, you can convert a file that was uploaded to memory directly to a django file. For a more complete example, let's say you wanted to upload a series of image files inside of a zip to the file system:

```
# some_app/models.py
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='some/upload/path')

...

# Upload code    
from some_app.models import Photo

for filename in uploaded_zip.namelist():
    with uploaded_zip.open(filename) as f:  # ZipExtFile
        new_photo = Photo()
        new_photo.image.save(filename, ContentFile(f.read(), save=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following django file class to avoid the need to read ZipExtFile into a another datastructure (StingIO or BytesIO) while properly impelementing what Django needs in order to save the file directly.

```
from django.core.files.base import File

class DjangoZipExtFile(File):
    def __init__(self, zipextfile, zipinfo):
        self.file = zipextfile
        self.zipinfo = zipinfo
        self.mode = 'r'
        self.name = zipinfo.filename
        self._size = zipinfo.file_size

    def seek(self, position):
        if position != 0:
            #this will raise an unsupported operation
            return self.file.seek(position)
        #TODO if we have already done a read, reopen file

zipextfile = archive.open(path, 'r')
zipinfo = archive.getinfo(path)
djangofile = DjangoZipExtFile(zipextfile, zipinfo)
storage = DefaultStorage()
result = storage.save(djangofile.name, djangofile)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the answer to read the zip contents (images) `in memory` and save them to database (ImageField) one by one. except I had to removed the `seek` method to get it to work. Plus it works for `Pillow` package :)